# How can I make Ansible execute plays in a specific order for server groups in my inventory file?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

How can I order hosts and make Ansible execute plays accordingly? I have an inventory file with two groups and each containing two servers under them.

Something like this:

```ini
[GROUP-A:children]
server-1
server-2
[GROUP-B:children]
server-1
server-2
```

I am trying to achieve a zero downtime deployment for my application and I am looking to make ansible execute playbook in the following order

1. GROUP-A --> server-1
2. GROUP-B --> server-1
3. GROUP-A --> server-2
4. GROUP-B --> server-2

I have tried serial:

```yaml
- hosts: "GROUP-A, GROUP-B"
  become: false
  gather_facts: true
  serial: 1
```

This limits Ansible to execute only on a single server from `GROUP-A`, `server-1`, which is what I want, but, I also need to jump to `GROUP-B`, `server-1` and achieve my execution order when the play repeats itself.

Comment: What are the reasons for `GROUP-A` and `GROUP-B`, usually your are splitting groups for different function but your use case makes it look like you are running the exact same playbook on both groups, regardless. Could you add in more "real life" context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no real magic in order to mix and match groups, what you could do is to run the first host of both groups then run all the subsequent hosts of those same groups, as demonstrated in the chapter [*"Using group position in patterns"*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_patterns.html#using-group-position-in-patterns) of the documentation:

```yaml
- hosts: GROUP-A[0], GROUP-B[0], GROUP-A[1:], GROUP-B[1:]
  serial: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the inventory

```ini
shell> cat hosts
[group_a]
server-1
server-2

[group_b]
server-3
server-4
```

---

Note: Group names should follow the same guidelines as [Creating valid variable names](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#creating-valid-variable-names). Quote: *" A variable name can only include letters, numbers, and underscores."*. *GROUP-A* and *GROUP-B* are not valid group names because of the dash *`-`*. You should have seen the warning:

> [WARNING]: Invalid characters were found in group names but not replaced, use -vvvv to see
> details

See: [Inventory basics: formats, hosts, and groups](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html#inventory-basics-formats-hosts-and-groups)

---

You can easily list the hosts on your own. In case the inventory is larger, you can declare the list of hosts. For example,

```yaml
hosts: "{{ groups.group_a|zip(groups.group_b)|flatten|join(',') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
hosts: 'server-1,server-3,server-2,server-4'
```

---

Example of a complete playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: "{{ groups.group_a|zip(groups.group_b)|flatten|join(',') }}"
  serial: 1
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: inventory_hostname
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml

PLAY [server-1,server-3,server-2,server-4] ***************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [server-1] => 
  inventory_hostname: server-1

PLAY [server-1,server-3,server-2,server-4] ***************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [server-3] => 
  inventory_hostname: server-3

PLAY [server-1,server-3,server-2,server-4] ***************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [server-2] => 
  inventory_hostname: server-2

PLAY [server-1,server-3,server-2,server-4] ***************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [server-4] => 
  inventory_hostname: server-4

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
server-1: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
server-2: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
server-3: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
server-4: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```